# cordova :: XMLHttpRequest :: setRequestHeader does not work with JSONP

Tags: ios, google-chrome, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, ripple

in hello world cordova 2.3.0 app trying to work with ripple

added basic BackboneJS code and I get error shown above

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.stackmob.com/js/json2-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.stackmob.com/js/underscore-1.4.3-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.stackmob.com/js/backbone-0.9.10-min.js"></script>
```

I have started google with the proper flags `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to disable "Cross Domain Proxy" in the Ripple settings.

Answer (score 1):

Change the "JSONP" with "JSON" and start chrome with these two options:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```